# How to differentiate between CLCircularRegion and CLBeaconRegion invoking didEnterRegion

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager

My app uses geofencing as well as `iBeacon` monitoring. I have set up some `CLCircularRegion` as well as `CLBeaconRegion` to be monitor. So whenever, i hit a new beacon or new location, then

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
NSLog(@"CLCircularRegion or CLBeaconRegion?, I am confused!!!");
}
```

will be invoked. Can anybody tell me how to find out which region(i.e.,CLCircularRegion/CLBeaconRegion) is calling the delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found my own answer.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
if (region.class == CLCircularRegion.class) {
        NSLog(@"CLCircularRegion")
    } else {
        NSLog("CLBeaconRegion")
  }

}
```